# Prove a set is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, arzela-ascoli

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric compact space and $F$ is the set of
> isometries from $X$ to itself. For every pair $f,g\in F$, define
> $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X} \rho(f(x),g(x)).$$ Prove that $d$ is a metric
> in $F$ and with that distance, prove $F$ is a metric compact space.

Let just pay attention to the part $F$ is compact (since it's easy to check $d$ is a metric in $F$).
My purpose is to apply Arzela Ascoli theorem

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a compact metric space, $(Y,d)$ is a complete metric
> space and $F$ is a subset of $C(X,Y)$ ($C(X,Y)$ is set of continuous
> mappings from $X$ to $Y$). Then $F$ is relatively compact
> $\iff\begin{cases}\forall x\in X,\{f(x)|f\in F\}\text{ is totally
>  bounded in } Y\\ F\text{ is equicontinuous on }X \end{cases}$

Consider $x_0\in X$.
$\forall\epsilon>0$, let choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then $\forall x\in X: \rho(x,x_0)<\delta,\forall f\in F$, we have $$\sup_{x\in X}\rho(f(x),f(x_0))=\sup_{x\in X}\rho(x,x_0)\leq\epsilon$$
$\Rightarrow F$ is equicontinuous on $X$.
Assume $\{f_n\}\subset F$ converges to $f$. Then $\rho(f_n(x),f_n(y))=\rho(x,y)\forall x,y\in X$.
Fixing $x,y$ and let $n\to\infty$, we have $\rho(f(x),f(y))=\rho(x,y).$
$\Rightarrow  f\in F\Rightarrow F$ is closed.
I just need to prove $F$ is totally bounded in $C[X,X]$ to finish the proof. But I don't know how to do it :( Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any subset of a compact metric space is totally bounded.

Comment: That means I have to $C[X,X]$ is compact. But how can I prove it?

Comment: $C[X,X]$ is not compact. When  $X=[0,1]$, $(x^{n})$ is  sequence in this space with no convegent subsequence w.r.t. sup norm.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks. Do you have any idea to prove $F$ is totally bounded in $C[X,X]$?

Comment: @leemax I mean, if you choose the entirety of $C[X, X]$, it won’t be equicontinuous, so this won’t imply it is compact.

Comment: @DavidGao can u explain your idea?

Comment: @leemax Assume $A \subset X$ and $X$ is compact. Pick a finite covering of $X$ by $\epsilon/2$-balls. For each such ball that intersects $A$, pick a point $x_n$ in the intersection. Then $\epsilon$-balls around $x_n$ cover $A$. This shows $A$ is totally bounded.

Comment: @DavidGao no , I mean what space does $F$ is subset of?

Comment: I still want to find a proof for the total bound of $F$.

Comment: @leemax I’m a bit confused. Arzela Ascoli theorem asks for total boundedness of $\{f(x): f \in F\}$ for each $x \in X$. And $\{f(x): f \in F\}$ is a subset of $X$.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify what Arzela Ascoli theorem says: a subset $F \subset C[X, Y]$ where $X$ is a compact metric space and $Y$ is a complete metric space is relatively compact iff it is equicontinuous (i.e., for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that whenever $d(x, y) < \delta$, we have $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ whenever $x, y \in X$ and $f \in F$) and for each $x \in X$, the set $\{f(x): f \in F\} \subset Y$ is totally bounded. You have shown that $F$, in your question, is equicontinuous…

Comment: I’m pointing out, in your case $Y = X$ is compact, and any subset of a compact space is automatically totally bounded, so in particular $\{f(x): f \in F\}$, being a subset of $Y$, is totally bounded. Thus, Arzela Ascoli theorem says your $F$ is relatively compact. Since you also showed it is closed in $C[X, X]$, this means it is compact. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is different approach: Let $(x_i)$ be a countable dense  set in $X$ and $(f_n)$ be  a sequence in $F$. By  a diagonal procedure show that there is  subsequnce $(n_i)$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty} f_{n_i}(x_k)$ exists for every $k$. A simple argument using the isometry property of $f_n$'s and triangle inequality shows that $f_{n_i}(x)$ is Cauchy, and hence convegent, for every $x\in X$. Let $f(x)=\lim_i f_{n_i}(x)$ and note that $d(f(x),f(y))=\lim_i d(f_{n_i}(x),f_{n_i}(y))=d(x,y)$. Thus, $f \in F$ and $f_{n_i} \to f$.